# cPanel Can't Open because IP address changes

Tags: ip, cpanel

I have a problem logging into my cpanel. each time I try to login it tells me my IP address has changed as in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDIUg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of

> IP address changed

is most common with the MTN ISP for most of us trying to access webhosting providers. These providers are usually configured not to allow certain type of proxy connection. The MTN ISP sometimes acts as a proxy connection causing the webhost to deny access and redirect the request with the message

> IP has changed

. To remedy or bypass such situations the following fix applies and works for me.

- Download and install **Thor Browser**. From my explanation, follows Thor browser in circumventing the MTN ISP phenomenon.
- Configure the browser such that your connection isn't being proxied.
- Launch the browser and enjoy your Hosting services at full strength over your 3G/4G connection.